# Como faço para pegar os dados de uma Entry e adicionar ao Banco de Dados (sqlite3)

Tags: banco-de-dados, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3

```
from tkinter import *

jan = Tk()
jan.title("Dados")
jan.geometry("200x200+250+100")

label = Label(jan, text="Nome:")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

nome = Entry(jan, width=25)
nome.grid(row=0,column=1)

label2 = Label(jan, text="Idade:")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

idade = Entry(jan, width=25)
idade.grid(row=1,column=1)

jan.mainloop()
```

## Queria Pegar a Entry e enviar os dados para o SQLite

Comment: Por favor gente, preciso muito da ajuda de vcs, quem poder dar uma ajudinha pfv se manifesta ai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia ! Você pode fazer desse jeito :

Primeiramente você tem que criar uma StringVar() para sua entry, dai então voce pode adicionar ao banco de dados

### criando a StringVar()

```
var1 = StringVar()
```

### Criando a Entry

```
nome = Entry(jan, width=25, textvariable = var1)
nome.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

### Adicionando ao banco de dados

```
var2 = var1.get()

cur = c.execute('INSERT INTO nomedatabela(colunaQueDesejaAdicionar) VALUES (?)',(var2,))
```

Answer (score 2):

Você tentou usar os atributos *nome.get()* e *idade.get()*? Vai retornar o conteudo da Entry. Você pode usar algo como `enviar = Button(jan, text='Enviar', command=lambda e: enviar(nome.get(), idade.get()));`
E fazer todo o tratamento nessa função Enviar.

Espero ter ajudado, também estou brincando com o tkinter, mas não sei trabalhar com o SQlite